# How to insert the data that's causing an error, into a separate file, while processing the rest of the column?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I'm making a program that handles over 20 million rows and over 50 columns of data. I'm trying to check if the numbers in one of the columns are even or odd.

If even, insert 'E' into a different column; if odd, insert 'O' into the column.

```
DF_FILE_IN = pd.read_csv('3MB_2.txt',chunksize=1000,sep='\t',dtype=str,engine='c',header=0,encoding='latin-1')
out_fields = ['HSNBR','OEFLAG']

for DF_FILE in DF_FILE_IN:
    df_out1 = pd.DataFrame(dtype='str',columns=out_fields)
    df_out1['HSNBR'] = DF_FILE['ANumber'].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>6}')

    df_out1.loc[pd.to_numeric(df_out1['HSNBR']).map(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0) & (x != 0)), 'OEFLAG'] = 'E'
    df_out1.loc[pd.to_numeric(df_out1['HSNBR']).map(lambda x: (x % 2 != 0) & (x != 0)), 'OEFLAG'] = 'O'
```

But some data has letters, symbols, spaces, etc.

When I run it, an error pops up from this line of code:
`df_out1.loc[pd.to_numeric(df_out1['HSNBR']).map(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0) & (x != 0)), 'OEFLAG'] = 'E'`

and says (example):

`ValueError: Unable to parse string "111 1/2g" at position 10`

I'm using chunking to pull in the data (eg. 1 million rows at a time). I am wanting to put the data that causes the errors into a separate file. But when I use `try except`, it doesn't process the column of data, in that chunk.

How do I get the data and errors into a file, while letting the program keep processing the column?

Comment: If they are separate files, use the `try except` block to catch `ValueErrors` for a different management. Based on your code it does not show the chunk or load parts

Comment: @BernardL I added more code for clarification.

Comment: I think then the best way to do that is to write a function that returns a arbitrary value when you it fails the operation. Then you will know which line is erroneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @BernardL means is to write a function like:

```
def even_odd(x):
    x = str(x)
    if x.isnumeric():
        x = int(x)
        if (x % 2 == 0) and (x != 0):
            return 'E'
        if (x % 2 != 0) and (x != 0):
            return 'O'
    return 'error'
```

And then apply it with:

```
df_out1['OEFLAG'] = df_out1['HSNBR'].map(even_odd)
```

And then you can take out the errors with:

```
df_out1[df_out1['OEFLAG'] == 'error'].to_csv('errors_file.csv')
df_out1 = df_out1[df_out1['OEFLAG'] != 'error']
```